# How to make Highcharts default pie not show when Angular page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, highcharts

So I have managed to get my HighCharts half-doughnut to display with hard-coded data. It displays just fine. I have now modified my code to get the data from the database and the slight delay that is causing is creating a problem for me where "Chart title" and a white box appears on the screen:

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="row container">
    <div class="col-md-2 greyBack loanWidget">
        <div class="calendarContainer">
            <div class="calendarTitle">{{myLoan.LoanStatus.Month}}</div>
            <div class="calendarDay">{{myLoan.LoanStatus.Day}}</div>
            <div class="calendarYear">{{myLoan.LoanStatus.Year}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 greyBack loanWidget" style="min-width: 200px; margin: 0; max-width: 200px; max-height: 171px; vertical-align: top;">
        <div ng-controller="LoanStatusChart">
            <highchart class="ng-cloak" config="highchartsNG" title="Wow" height="171"></highchart>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--<div id="container" class="col-md-4 greyBack loanWidget" style="min-width: 200px; margin: 0; max-width: 200px; max-height: 300px; vertical-align: top;"></div>-->
    <div class="col-md-3 greyBack loanWidget balance">
        <span class="balanceText">{{myLoan.LoanStatus.OriginalPrincipalBalance}}</span><br />
        <span class="balanceTextLabel">Outstanding Balance</span><br />
        <span class="borrowedText">{{myLoan.LoanStatus.BorrowedAmt}}</span><br />
        <span class="borrowedTextLabel">Borrowed</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 loanWidget"><img src="../images/c4l/cfl-banner.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Here is my Angular code:

```
cflApp.controller('LoanStatusChart', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {

    $scope.$watch("myLoan.LoanNumber", function (value) {
        if (value) {
            var urlBase = '/api/C4L/';
            var loanNumber = value;
            $http.get(urlBase + 'TheLoanInfo?loanNumberText=' + loanNumber).success(function (data, status) {
                var myPaidOff = data.LoanStatus.PaidOff;
                var myStillOwed = 100 - myPaidOff;
                $scope.options = {
                    type: 'pie',
                    colors: ['#971a31', '#ffffff']
                }


                $scope.highchartsNG = {
                    options: {
                        plotOptions: {
                            pie: {
                                borderColor: '#000000',
                                size: 115,
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: false,
                                    distance: -50,
                                    style: {
                                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                                        color: 'white',
                                        textShadow: '0px 1px 2px black',

                                    }

                                },
                                startAngle: -90,
                                endAngle: 90,
                                center: ['30%', '75%']
                            }
                        },
                        colors: ['#971a31', '#ffffff'],
                        chart: {
                            type: 'pie',
                            backgroundColor: '#f1f1f2',
                            height: 180,
                            className: 'half-doughnut',
                            animation: {
                                duration: 1500
                            }
                        },
                        credits: false
                    },
                    chart: {
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: 0,
                        plotShadow: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: Math.round(myPaidOff) + '%<br />Paid Off',
                        style: {
                            color: '#971a31',
                            fontWEight: 'bold',
                            fontSize: '15px'
                        },
                        verticvalAlign: 'middle',
                        y: 120,
                        x: -24
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                    },

                    series: [{
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: 'Loan',
                        innerSize: '80%',
                        data: [
                            [Math.round(myPaidOff) + '% paid', Math.round(myPaidOff)],
                            [Math.round(myStillOwed) + '% owed', Math.round(myStillOwed)]

                        ]
                    }],
                    loading: false
                }
            }).error("error message");
        }

    });

});
```

I have attempted to set a class called "hidden-chart" on the div that displays the chart and then to use JQuery to show it when app.run is fired, but the hidden-chart div isn't reappearing. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you receive errors in the console, how your data looks like? Because it seems that is incorrect.

Comment: no errors and the data is simply:

"85% paid off", 85

Just that one row right now

Comment: I mean this value: myPaidOff, check if it is number not string

Comment: It is definitely a number because I use parseFloat(myPaidOff) to insure the variable is a number.

Comment: Are you able to recreate it as live demo?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this because I found the answer. Because we are using Angular.js we needed to add the code inside of the directive responsible for the partial the chart was appearing in. Thus, we moved that same code I displayed inside of the directive as follows:

```
cflApp.directive('yourMortgage', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/partial/yourMortgage.html',
        link: function ($scope, element, attributes) {
            $scope.options = {
                type: 'pie',
                colors: ['#971a31', '#ffffff']
            }

            $scope.highchartsNG = {
                options: {
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            borderColor: '#000000',
                            size: 115,
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false,
                                distance: -50,
                                style: {
                                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                                    color: 'white',
                                    textShadow: '0px 1px 2px black',

                                }

                            },
                            startAngle: -90,
                            endAngle: 90,
                            center: ['30%', '75%']
                        }
                    },
                    colors: ['#971a31', '#ffffff'],
                    chart: {
                        type: 'pie',
                        backgroundColor: '#f1f1f2',
                        height: 180,
                        className: 'half-doughnut',
                        animation: {
                            duration: 1500
                        }
                    },
                    credits: false
                },
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: 0,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Paid Off',
                    style: {
                        color: '#971a31',
                        fontWEight: 'bold',
                        fontSize: '15px'
                    },
                    verticvalAlign: 'middle',
                    y: 120,
                    x: -24
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Loan',
                    innerSize: '80%',
                }],
                loading: false
            }

        }

    }
});
```

That fixed the flashing problem and allowed the control to only load when the page was rendered.